# Problems iterating and displaying results from flask api when using Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, flask

I'm following a Flask/Vue tutorial for the first time (found at https://testdriven.io/blog/developing-a-single-page-app-with-flask-and-vuejs/) and I'm trying to adapt it to suit my needs. To save listing the full code, the parts I seem to be having a problem with are here:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Note</th>
              <th scope="col">User</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(note, index) in notes" :key="index">
              <td>{{ note.note }}</td>
              <td>{{ note.index }}</td>
              <td>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                  <button
                          type="button"
                          class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"
                          v-b-modal.note-update-modal
                          @click="editNote(note)">
                      Update
                  </button>
                  <button
                          type="button"
                          class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                          @click="onDeleteNote(note)">
                      Delete
                  </button>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

and the function that updates the html table on `created()` is:

```
  methods: {
    getNotes() {
      const path = 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/resources/notes/';
      axios.get(path)
        .then((res) => {
          this.notes = res.data.notes;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          console.error(error);
        });
    },
...
```

For some reason, in the tutorial version the HTML table updates with the database elements perfectly, but when I try after changing the field names it won't, and I cant spot my error.

I've tried doing a console.log(res) instead of the function and it logs the data, it just seems that the function provided won't work using my field names.

Can anyone put a beginner out of his misery?

Thanks in advance

Comment: so what does `console.log(res.data)` produce?

Comment: if your `res.data.notes` exists, can you try console.log(this.notes) after `this.notes = res.data.notes`

Comment: console.log(res.data) produces 
```0: {Note: "This is my first entry", User: "Nicky ", id: 1}
1: {Note: "test", User: "Nicky", id: 2}
2: {Note: "test", User: "Nicky", id: 3}
3: {Note: "test", User: "Nicky", id: 4}
4: {Note: "test again", User: "Nicky", id: 5}
5: {Note: "test again", User: "Nicky", id: 6}```

which is my dummy data from the database, which I'm wanting to update the html field with. 

console.log(this.notes) produces an error, "unexpected console"

Comment: well there ya go, there is no `notes` property in your data from api. Seems it is an array. also note (pun intended) the uppercase `Note`, not `note`.

Comment: ok, so its about how the data is being returned from the api, rather than how I'm handling it on the frontend. Thank you, I'll look at that. I just thought it was a syntax problem somewhere.

Comment: No, no syntax issue, you just need to match your properties. So you should assign the data with: `this.notes = res.data` and in your template iteration you need to show `note.Note` as it is uppercase.

Comment: Just to confirm, that's now working as I expected! Thanks so much for the help